# segmentation fault from threads

Tags: c, pthreads, dynamic-memory-allocation

I have written the code below but when I run it it brings segmentation fault. It compiles correctly though. Where are my mistakes?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <pthread.h>
static int N = 5;
static void* run(void *arg) {
  int *i = (int *) arg;
  char buf[123];
  snprintf(buf, sizeof(buf), "thread %d", *i);
  return buf;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
  int i;
  pthread_t *pt = NULL;
  for (i = 0; i < N; i++) {
    pthread_create(pt, NULL, run, &i);
  }
  return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Any hint is welcomed.

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have serveral issues:

1) You are passing a NULL to `pthread_create()` which is probably the reason for segfault.

2) You don't wait for the threads to complete (when `main` thread exits the whole process dies).

3) You are passing the address same variable `i` to all threads. This is a *data race*.

4) You are returning the address of a local variable `buf` from the thread function.

You can fix it like:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <pthread.h>
static int N = 5;
static void* run(void *arg) {
  int *i = (int *) arg;
  char *buf = malloc(16);
  snprintf(buf, 16, "thread %d", *i);
  return buf;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
  int i;
  void *ret;
  int arr[N];
  pthread_t pt[N];

  for (i = 0; i < N; i++) {
    arr[i] = i;
    pthread_create(&pt[i], NULL, run, &arr[i]);
  }

  for (i = 0; i < N; i++) {
    pthread_join(pt[i], &ret);
    printf("Thread %d returned: %s\n", i, (char*)ret);
    free(ret);
  }
  return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Note that you don't need to use `pthread_join()` calls. You can also cal `pthread_exit()` from the main thread so that only the main thread exit and other threads continue.